# Make one HTML form look like other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the below screen shot `State` is a server linked element that pulls state name using the country name from the database. Unfortunately previous developer developed this using PHP code with `<SPAN></SPAN>` and was developed in framework Kohana (which I have no knowledge in) and its getting me hard to make the `State` element look like other dropdox boxes. Is there any easy way to make the `State` field look like the other dropdown boxes? I tried many ways in CSS but couldn't bring the exact feel.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">                                       
    <label>State</label>                                        
    <div class="holder">                                                                                             
        <input type="text" max="20" id="state-input" name="stateInput" value="" style="display: none;">
    </div>          
    <span class="select-area" style="width: 205px;">
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="center">Please select a country first</span>
    <a class="select-opener"></a></span>
    <select id="state-select" name="stateSelect" style="margin-left: 8px;" class="jcf-hidden">                                          
        <option value="">Please select a country first</option>
    </select>                                                                            
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you need to give us a fiddle.

Comment: Did you already check your CSS to see if there are any specifications for #state-select or .jcf-hidden? It might be that all you need to do is match styles between the Country `select` lists and the State `select` lists. Alternatively, is there a Javascript that is targeting #state-select to make the UI different? I'd check those things, and try disabling things one at a time until you find what is triggering the style change.

Comment: @Krishna if the OP could reproduce this in a fiddle, they wouldn't be asking the question. 

@lock right-click the dropdown and select 'Inspect element'. Chrome will open the web inspector, which displays the CSS applied. Somewhere you will find a rule specifying `color` and `background-color`. Find that passage in your CSS and remove it!

Comment: @Barney - why do you think its not reproducible? obviously the CSS is different for both the cases. copy pasting the html & CSS in a fiddle is all he needs.

Comment: @Krishna you're right, it could be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you can remove all between div class="row"  and "select" in select remove class jcf-hidden.`<div class="row">

    <select id="state-select" name="stateSelect" style="margin-left: 8px;">

        <option value="">Please select a country first</option>
    </select>

</div>`
the best and fast method to see what style is applied to the element is to use developer console in Chrome.